# a function has 2 extreme points (conditions)

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have this function $f:(-1,\infty )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=ax^2+1-ln(1+x),a\in \mathbb{R}$

I need to find $a$ so this function to have 2 extreme points.

I found the derivative which is $f'(x)=\frac{2ax(1+x)-1}{1+x}$ so $2ax^2+2ax-1=0$ and now I put the condition so this equation to have solutions $(the \ discriminant>0)$ and  I got $4a^2+8a>0\Rightarrow a\in (-\infty ,-2)\cup (0,\infty )$
How should I continue ? Because the final result is $a<-2$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

the roots of the quadratic are
$$\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+2a}}{2a}$$

$$=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+\frac 2a}}{2}$$

they must be in $(-1,+\infty)$.